# Mysql query sum and find average

Tags: mysql, sum, average

I have a db table which stores votes made against articles. I would like to query the table to find, within the last 30 days, the articles which on average have received the best overall votes.

I'm looking for some advice on how I should do this, I am guessing I can either do this with PHP or MYSQL. Although I have a better grasp of PHP I would imagine that using MYSQL to get my result is better practice.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ratings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rating` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=2054 ;
```

Is there a way to sum and find an average given this table structure.

Thnak you.

Alan.

Comment: `SELECT AVG(rating) avgrating
FROM ratings GROUP BY article_id WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) ORDER BY avgrating DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function AVG() in MySQL. So

```
SELECT AVG(rating) 
FROM ratings
WHERE article_id = 1
```

Will give the average rating of the articles with article_id 1.

There's also a SUM() function in MySQL. So

```
SELECT SUM(rating) 
FROM ratings
WHERE article_id = 1
```

Will give the sum of all ratings of the articles with article_id 1.

Comment: Great thank you I did not think it would be that easy, much more straightforward than trying to grab the data and sort it with a php script!

Comment: Good luck with it! Note: It won't take 'rating'-fields with value NULL. So if you have 1, 3, 5, NULL, 10: average will be 19/4=4.75, not 19/5=3.8. If you want it to also take NULL fields you could do it by using SUM()/COUNT(). But I suppose you don't want that.   ---EDIT// Nevermind, rating is a NOT NULL field.